# Transform a JSON object to a JSON array, taking the first level of properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've this JSON object

```
{
    "08f4f705-6e14-4781-8241-d04bf2dc6ada": {
        "description": "xxxxxxxx",
        "note": "yyyyyyyy"
     },
    "05f4f995-6e14-4567-8241-d04bf2d456ee": {
        "description": "aaaaaa",
        "note": "bbb"
     },
    "0675f995-6e14-4567-8241-d4567f2d456z": {
        "description": "fffff",
        "note": "gggg"
     }
}
```

I need to convert into a JSON array like this:
(the elements should be the content of the first level properties)

```
[
    {
       "description": "xxxxxxxx",
       "note": "yyyyyyyy"
    },
    {
       "description": "aaaaaa",
       "note": "bbb"
    },
    {
       "description": "fffff",
       "note": "gggg"
    }
]
```

I can't manipulate the object and I didn't find an appropriate resource to follow.  How can I do it?

Comment: where is the problem? `ParseToDictionary(json).Values.ToJson()` should work

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by deserializing your json string into `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

After that you extract the values and serialize them back to json:

```
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.Values);
```